# How to call two calloc and use strncpy() to copy strings

Tags: c

I was told to use two callocs and one strncpy() to complete the task.

```
    
    Person_t* newPerson(char* name, int age, double height)
    {
      size_t len = strlen(name)+1;
      name = calloc(len, sizeof(char));
      Person_t* person = calloc(1, sizeof(Person_t));
      person->name = strdup(name);
      person->age = age;
      person->height = height;
      return person;
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post text as an image. Copy (or type it out) as text into the question. Also, "can't get the desired result" is not very useful - what result *did* you get?

Comment: You're forgetting about null terminators. Also, `strncpy` does not null terminate if there is no room. It is a bad function to use for this job

Comment: `calloc(len, sizeof(Person_t))` should be `calloc(1, sizeof(Person_t))` and then to copy the name do `person->name = strdup(name)`. Don't forget to `free(person->name)`

Comment: You need to allocate `strlen(name) + 1`.  But you are discarding the value of the parameter that was passed in when you write `name = calloc(...)`.  Before you made that call, `name` pointed to a string that you want to copy.  After you make that call, `name` points to a different location, and you've lost the old value.

Comment: The "person calloc" doesn't "use size 1". It allocates 1 object of size `sizeof(Person_t)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are discarding the value "Billy" when you assign the value returned by `calloc` to `name`.  Before that call, `name` pointed to the string literal "Billy".  After that call, it points to zeroed out memory.  As the question currently stands, you just need to delete the line

```
name = calloc(...);
```

If you want to `calloc`, you need to assign the returned value to `person->name` instead of `name`.  eg:

```
  person->name = calloc(len + 1, sizeof *person->name);
  strncpy(person->name, name, len + 1);
```

or just replace both of those lines with:

```
person->name = strdup(name);
```

(just make sure you haven't assigned name to something else before you do this.)

You don't need to use `len + 1` in the `strncpy` since `calloc` has already written the zero so there's no need to copy the null terminator, but it doesn't hurt.  You definitely need `len + 1` in the calloc, to allocate space for the null terminator.  And you certainly need to assign that allocated space to `person->name`, not to `name`, since assigning to `name` here would discard the value that you are trying to copy.  (Note, the question has been edited.  Previously, `len` was just `strlen(name)`, but now `len` is `strlen(name) + 1`.  I'll leave the `+1` here for safety's sake.  It seldom hurts to over-allocate, but under-allocation is often a serious problem.